# Feature image field is not showing in dashboard for custom post type

Tags: image, backend, field, custom-post-type, dashboard

I want my result like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2oqR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'supports' parameter missed in your custom post type. Just add following code where you registered your custom post type.

`'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),`